# How to examine rspec variables with pry debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rspec, rspec-rails, pry

I've seen some SO posts explaining how to use pry to step into rspec tests and been able to do this. Once I reach the breakpoint though, I'm struggling to display any useful information.  For this code below, I'd like to examine the response object from the pry console:

```
describe 'happenings' do
  context "#index (GET /api/v1/flat_happenings.json)" do
    before(:each) do
      30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:flat_happening) }
      get "/api/v1/flat_happenings.json"
    end
    describe "should list all flat_happenings" do
      binding.pry
      it { JSON.parse(response.body)["flat_happenings"].length.should eq 30 }
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should place `binding.pry` inside `it` block.

Answer (score 26):

To use pry in specs we need to add `require 'pry'` within the spec_helper.rb file. Then we are able to use binding.pry within any of the specs.

Comment: It may not be recommend to add `require 'pry'` to a `spec_helper.rb` file if your project defines `pry` as a development dependency, as opposed to a Runtime dependency.  Pry is a development gem that might not be recommend on a release of your library.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
describe 'happenings' do
  context "#index (GET /api/v1/flat_happenings.json)" do
    before(:each) do
      30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:flat_happening) }
      get "/api/v1/flat_happenings.json"
    end
    it "should list all flat_happenings" do
      binding.pry
      JSON.parse(response.body)["flat_happenings"].length.should eq 30
    end
  end
end
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer works too but as Sergey answered first, I have had to accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I try to require pry when I actually use it, otherwise, it might introduce some unusual bugs (unusual but it can happen)
So that means if you only want to debug a particular test, you don't need to `require 'pry'` in your `spec_helper.rb` you can use `require 'pry'` just in the test you want to debug.

```
def method_i_am_debugging
  puts 'does stuff'
  require 'pry'
  binding.pry
  # ...
end
```